# how to consume response object in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I am using ionic2, and I'am using http post request to get data from webservice and the returned data is:

> Response {_body: "{"Status":{"list all categories":[{"id":9,"name_en…18}],"message":["All categories."],"version":27}}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers…}
>   headers
>   :
>   Headers
>   ok
>   :
>   true
>   status
>   :
>   200
>   statusText
>   :
>   "OK"
>   type
>   :
>   2
>   url
>   :
>   "http://safe-pay.co/safepay/public/api/user"
>   _body
>   :
>   "{"Status":{"list all categories":[{"id":9,"name_en":"Telecom","name_ar":"\u0627\u062a\u0635\u0627\u0644\u0627\u062a","image":"http://safe-pay.co/safepay/public/uploadedimg/categories/5937ec7b75164.PNG","description":"Telecom","cat_enet_id":1},{"id":7,"name_en":"Online Vouchers","name_ar":"\u0628\u0637\u0627\u0642\u0627\u062a \u062a\u0633\u0648\u0642 \u0639\u0628\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0646\u062a\u0631\u0646\u062a","image":"http://safe-pay.co/safepay/public/uploadedimg/categories/5937f109a226b.png","description":"Online Voucher","cat_enet_id":5},{"id":8,"name_en":"TV Channels","name_ar":"\u0645\u062d\u0637\u0627\u062a \u062a\u0644\u0641\u0632\u064a\u0648\u0646\u064a\u0629","image":"http://safe-pay.co/safepay/public/uploadedimg/categories/5937ecb48cef3.PNG","description":"TV channels","cat_enet_id":6},{"id":10,"name_en":"Digital Games","name_ar":"\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0628 \u0627\u0646\u062a\u0631\u0646\u062a","image":"http://safe-pay.co/safepay/public/uploadedimg/categories/5937eccc27ce8.png","description":"Games","cat_enet_id":17},{"id":11,"name_en":"Entertainment","name_ar":"\u0627\u0644\u062a\u0631\u0641\u064a\u0647 \u0644\u0644\u0623\u0637\u0641\u0627\u0644","image":"http://safe-pay.co/safepay/public/uploadedimg/categories/5937f5ae97fe6.png","description":"Games","cat_enet_id":18}],"message":["All categories."],"version":27}}"
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Body

this is the function:

```
getCategories() {
let objData = {"Data":{
        "action": "CATEGORIES",
        "lang": "AR"
    },
    "Request": {

    }
}

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

this.http.post(this.userUrl, objData, {headers:headers})
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.categories = data
        console.log("categories array ",this.categories," data ",Promise.resolve(data));
    }, error => {
        console.log("Oooops! ",error);
    });
}
```

how can I get the data from the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be mapping it to `json()` format

```
this.http.post(this.userUrl, objData, {headers:headers})
         .map(response=><T>response.json())
         ...
```

Note: importing map operator is required which can be done from

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

and `T` type to which you want to convert the json().

Comment: @Al-shimaaAdel happy to help you. :) need more help or your clear?

Comment: thanks alot, i get the data that i want:(5) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] but if i subscribe in the provider the data doesn't found else if i subscribe in the page i get into infinit loop of requests